# Enable craft.log for console commands

Tags: logging, console

I've got `devMode` enabled and can see the log happening in `craft/storage/runtime/logs/craft.log` for browser requests... but was wondering if there is a way to enable this level of logging (detailing every sql etc.) for console commands in plugins?

Comment: Per Brad's answer, this is a bug which has been fixed for the next release. Closing as a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Craft that's been fixed for the next ([post 2.4.2696](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2696)) release.

Once that release is out, [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) output will be written to the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files just like a normal web request would with devMode enabled.